# HTML Doesn't Show in Xcode?

Tags: javascript, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I have built an game using HTML and javascript that I want to turn into an ipad app. 
I have been following this "Creating a native 'Objective-C' app" section of this guide: http://matt.might.net/articles/how-to-native-iphone-ipad-apps-in-javascript/

However, when I run the ipad simulator in Xcode, the "ipad" comes up, but it just shows a blank screen. 
I took out all my code in my html file and just put in a couple of lines of html. When I change the background color, this does show in the ipad simulator. 
However no text shows up.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

I am using Xcode 3. Also, I have already taken my javascript file out of "compile sources" and placed it into "copy bundle resource".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your problem but an easy way to create an HTML/JS app is to use PhoneGap. Plus you can bring your app to other OS like Android an a PhoneGap project is really easy to set up.

http://phonegap.com/start